# I need to run a elastic search query where at-least one of few terms in few fields are mandatory and one other term in a field is mandatory

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run a query equivalent to the following code on elastic search

```java
if((creator==2 || creator==4 || assignee==8 || assignee==10) && (zone=="Hyderabad") &&(message=="Hello World"))
{
    return document;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query what you are looking for. I've made use of [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for e.g. `must` as `AND` operation and `should` as `OR` operation.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "zone":"hyderabad"
               }
            },
            {  
               "match":{  
                  "message":"hello world"
               }
            },
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "should":[  
                     {  
                        "match":{  
                           "creator":2
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "match":{  
                           "creator":4
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "match":{  
                           "assignee":6
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "match":{  
                           "assignee":8
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "minimum_should_match":1
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Also note that I've used all searchable words in small caps. To know why read about [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html).

I'd also suggest you spend sometime in reading about the below links:
[Text Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) and [Keyword Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did the above query solve what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. Somehow, I have acheived the soluton using following query.

Comment: {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {"term": {"creatorId": 3099}},
          {"term": {"assignedToId": 3099}},
          {"term": {"creatorId": 3111}},
          {"term": {"assignedToId": 3111}}
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "must": [
         {"query_string": {"fields": ["nameOrCompanyname"],"query": "*Mickey*"}}
         ]
      }
    },
    "sort": [
     {"id": {"order": "desc"}}
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
  }

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Cool. I just hope my query at least gave you an idea as how it can be done. Also it would be useful if you post mapping, next time you ask a question. That way people could help you in better way ;)

Comment: Your answer brought me too close to the solution. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as follows:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {"term": {"creatorId": 3099}},
          {"term": {"assignedToId": 3099}},
          {"term": {"creatorId": 3111}},
          {"term": {"assignedToId": 3111}}
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "must": [
            {"query_string": {"fields": ["message"],"query": "Hello World"}},
            {"query_string": {"fields": ["zone"],"query": "Hyderabad"}}
            ]
      }
    },
    "sort": [
        {"id": {"order": "desc"}}
    ],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
  }
```